# How to prevent Text from expanding the width of a VStack

Tags: swiftui

I have a `VStack` that contains an `Image` and a `Text`. I am setting the width (and height) of the Image to be half of the screen's width:

```
struct PopularNow: View {
    let item = popular[0]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 5) {
            Image(item.image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: getRect().width/2, height: getRect().width/2)
            Text(item.description)
                .font(.caption)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .lineLimit(0)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
        .cornerRadius(15)
    }
    
    func getRect() -> CGRect {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Text` pushes and causes the `VStack` to expand instead of respecting the `Image`'s width. How can I tell the `Text` to not grow horizontally more than the `Image` width and to grow "vertically" (i.e. add as many lines it needs)? I know that I can add the `frame` modifier to `VStack` itself, but it seems like a hack. I want to tell the `Text` to only take as much space width wise as `VStack` already has, not more.

This is what it looks like right now, as you can see the VStack is not half the screen's size, it's full screen size because the `Text` is expanding it.

[image: screenshot of app]

Comment: Why are you specifying `.lineLimit(0)`. According to documentation, if you don't want a limit, you should pass `nil` - `.lineLimit(nil)`, which I think is the default anyway

Comment: @swiftPunk something like priorities in UIKit. That type of logic...

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix its size, like

```
    VStack(spacing: 5) {
        Image(item.image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: getRect().width/2, height: getRect().width/2)
        Text(item.description)
            .font(.caption)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .lineLimit(0)
    }
    .fixedSize()         // << here !!
//   .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)   // alternate
    .padding()
```